# How to calculate rotation speed based on deltax?

Tags: c, rotation, game-physics, game-development

To give context, I'm trying to clone [Wolfenstein 3D](https://www.retrogames.cz/play_408-DOS.php?language=EN) using C. I'm at a position where my game is fully functional and can move and rotate point of view using keys, however i'm trying to add the functionality of changing point of view using mouse too, and i managed to do so but the result is not as expected.

in my key based rotation I have a constant variable with which the player rotate at a constant speed all the time, however with mouse it's a bit different the user move the cursor fast or slow and depending in the latter rotation speed should be incremented or decremented accordingly, to just imitate the latter , i coded a stupid `if else` tree to configure `rotation speed of the player`, something as basic as that:

```
diff = abs(x - prev_x);
if (diff < 100)
        rot_spd = degtorad(2);
    else if (diff > 100 && diff < 200)
        rot_spd = degtorad(3);
    else if (diff > 200 && diff < 300)
        rot_spd = degtorad(4);
    ...
```

The question is:

given a `deltaX = abs(x - pervious_x)`  where `x` and `pervious_x` is position of cursor at a given time is there a mathematical formula or a better a way than `if else` to configure with which speed in degrees the player will rotate the `Point of view`.

Comment: Just a guess: keyboard is different than mouse. For a given mouse deltaX, you want a [scaled] delta rotation _increment_ and _not_ a rotation speed/velocity. So, `new_rot = old_rot + (scale * deltaX)`

Answer (score 0):

Based on the numbers you have used in your if / else expressions you could use:

```
diff = abs(x - prev_x);
rot_spd = degtorad(diff / 100 + 2);
```

This assumes diff is an integer type, so that when divided the fractional part of the result is discarded and the result is truncated towards zero.

It will also cover the cases where diff is an exact multiple of 100, which your code does not cater for just now. You would need to add an equality check in your if else expressions.

Comment: The above example is just as random as it can gets to just put a working prototype,  i'm sure there's a solid formula to configure rotation speed which i couldn't found googling, so i posted here in the hope of finding it, 100 chosen above is completely random and doesn't yeild the intended smoothness in rotation